# xunit.runner.dnx on visual studio online no tests found

Tags: azure-devops, xunit, dnx

In Visual studio online , i have got a dnx project to work and its all looking very good .

However while the test projects finds the test assemblies it doesnt find tests in them. It does work in visual studio locally.

Here is the log

```
> 2015-06-10T12:44:40.4024316Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line
> Tool Version 14.0.22823.1
> 
> 6  2015-06-10T12:44:40.4034315Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. 
> All rights reserved.
> 
> 7  2015-06-10T12:44:40.9083471Z Starting test execution, please
> wait...
> 
> 8  2015-06-10T12:44:41.0261699Z Warning: Using Isolation mode to run
> the tests as diagnostic data adapters were enabled in the runsettings.
> Use the /inIsolation parameter to suppress this warning.
> 
> 9  2015-06-10T12:44:57.8605322Z Warning: No test is available in
> C:\a\2b7cb926\Anne Prototype\ANNe\artifacts\bin\Test.ANNe.Compiler\Debug\dnx451\Test.ANNe.Compiler.dll
> C:\a\2b7cb926\Anne
> Prototype\ANNe\artifacts\bin\Test.ANNe.Compiler\Debug\dnxcore50\Test.ANNe.Compiler.dll
> C:\a\2b7cb926\Anne
> Prototype\ANNe\artifacts\bin\Test.ANNe.Core\Debug\dnx451\Test.ANNe.Core.dll
> C:\a\2b7cb926\Anne
> Prototype\ANNe\artifacts\bin\Test.ANNe.Core\Debug\dnxcore50\Test.ANNe.Core.dll
> C:\a\2b7cb926\Anne
> Prototype\ANNe\artifacts\bin\Test.Console\Debug\dnx451\Test.Console.dll
> C:\a\2b7cb926\Anne
> Prototype\ANNe\artifacts\bin\Test.Console\Debug\dnxcore50\Test.Console.dll.
> Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform &
> framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
> 
> 10  2015-06-10T12:44:58.0834255Z Attachments:
> 
> 11  2015-06-10T12:44:58.0874253Z  
> C:\a\2b7cb926\TestResults\daa5a111-9c85-40a3-930d-d5a511bbf1ee\buildguest_TASKAGENT-0001
> 2015-06-10 12_44_50.coverage
> 
> 12  2015-06-10T12:44:58.1054246Z Information: Additionally, you can
> try specifying '/UseVsixExtensions' command if the test discoverer &
> executor is installed on the machine as vsix extensions and your
> installation supports vsix extensions. Example: vstest.console.exe
> myTests.dll /UseVsixExtensions:true
> 
> 13  2015-06-10T12:44:58.3310571Z ##[warning]No results found to
> publish.
```

Runner is set in project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0-beta2-build2981",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta2-build79"
},
```

Id like to not use my own build server at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to install somethin in visual studio to get this to work? Unfortunately as the build dev get is not owned by you you will not be able to run this tests that require a plugin. Both MSTest and nUnit are supported.

Comment: No don't need to install anything ... however it does integrate into VS test it must pick up there is a dll ,  somehow it needs to be told the runner is xunit.runner.dnx. This is automatic in VS locally .

Comment: Then It does need the year runner installed. Is It does in Nuget or vsix?

Comment: All i did was add the runner to project.json which uses nuget. I use a powershell script to insttall dnx before the build.

Comment: Please describe "install dnx"? You do not have permission to install anything on the hosted build server.

Comment: & $env:USERPROFILE\.dnx\bin\dnvm install $dnxVersion -r coreclr -arch x64 -nonative   works

Comment: That sounds like something you would not have permission to do on a server that you do not own.

Comment: It does work .. I build it using the default agent. Its the tests i cant get working.